# Can LaTeX spread a table of ordered sets over multiple columns?

Tags: tables

I have a list of items that need to be flanked by a check box and a blank space for handwriting. The list needs to go down the page about 20 lines and then move to the next column. I plan on putting other tables above and below this oddball table.

I coded this up, but it looks pretty horrible. Thanks in advance if you know of any solutions.

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
Skills

\hrulefill
\end{center}
\begin{tabular}[t]{clc}
\HollowBox & Accounting 10\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Anthropology 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Archaeology 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Art 05\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Astronomy 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Bargain 05\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Biology 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Brawl 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Chemistry 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Climb 40\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Computer Use 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Conceal 15\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Craft 05\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Credit Rating 15\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Cthulhu Mythos 00\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Disguise 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Dodge (DEX x2\%) & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Drive 20\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Electrical Repair 10\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Electronics 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{clc}
\HollowBox & Fast Talk 05\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & First Aid 30\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Geology 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Grapple 25\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Handgun 20\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Hide 10\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & History 20\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Jump 25\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Law 25\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Library Use 25\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Listen 25\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Locksmith 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Machine Gun 15\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Martial Arts 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Machine Repair 20\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Medicine 05\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Natural History 10\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Navigate 10\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Occult 05\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Heavy Machinery 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{clc}
\HollowBox & Other Lang. 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Own Lang. (EDU x5\%) & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Persuade (Oratory) 15\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\   
\HollowBox & Pharmacy 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Photography 10\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Physics 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Pilot 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Psychoanalysis 01\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Psychology 05\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Ride 05\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Rifle 25\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Shotgun 30\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Sneak 10\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Spot Hidden 25\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Submachine Gun 15\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Swim 25\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Throw 25\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\HollowBox & Track 10\% & \_\_\_\_\_ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: What is `\HollowBoc`? How we can compile your code snipped if you not provide any information of document preamble and `\documentclass`? Please, improve your question.